# Secure Oozie Web Console not working from my Windows machine

Tags: hadoop, kerberos, oozie

I have setup a secure(Kerberos) Oozie environment in CentOS 6.3 using CDH 4.1.2. I am able to view the Oozie web console from CentOS machine which is hosted in server. But is there a way to view the webconsole from my local Windows machine.

I have tried creating a HTTP principal with my windows machine as hostname. I am able to get a valid ticket for HTTP principal. But when I open the Oozie Web Console, I get the following error

**org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.client.AuthenticationException: GSSException: Defective token detected (Mechanism level: GSSHeader did not find the right tag)**

Am I missing something. Help me guys.

Thanks,

Vishnu Ganth

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs because your browser sends request for NTLM authentication instead of kerberos.

In internet explorer follow below steps,

1. go to **Internet Options**
2. In **security** tab, select **Local intranet**.
3. Click **Custom Level** in the below, Make sure **Automatic logon only in intranet zone** under the **User Authentication** section.
4. In the **Internet Options**, select **Advanced** tab and make sure enable **Integrated Windows Authentication** selected under security section.

Once the above steps done, it will work on both internet explorer and google chrome.

Answer (score 0):

If you are accesing it from the Cross realm, your widows-based clients should know the KDC location to create proper SPNEGO token. You need either create a separate policy in your AD for that type of users or you can manually from command line add mappings in client machine's registeries so that they would know about your Hadoop realm KDC:

ksetup /addkdc HADOOP.DOMAIN.COM hadoop.nodewithkdc.com

ksetup /addhosttorealmmap hadoop.nodewithkdc.com HADOOP.DOMAIN.COM